MDS for Products with two Dimensions
I am currently struggling to perform a MDS Analysis for my Master thesis.
I gathered data on how different products are perceived concerning their level of involvement and their think-feel dimension. So in spss I have both the aggregated involvement values of a product(Dimension 1) and and the aggregated think-feel values (dimension 2)



pro1_inv
pro1_think-feel




4.5
3.5



So I have data on 31 Products, all with those 2 dimensions (62 Variables)
How do I conduct a MDS with those 2 dimension illustrated as one product (pro1_inv and pro1_think-feel should be illustrated as Product 1 in the MDS)
Many thanks in advance
I tried putting the product names in the variable slot and had the aggregated involvement values in row 1 and ThinkFeel in row 2. Also I have watched every single tutorial and read a lot of instructions but still no progress
